# how to use if else in jquery ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to fetch records on the bases of search data and if search data is empty  than load 
another page as i used the ajax code as below

```
function search_alumni()
 {

         $data = $('#search_alumni').val();
         if($data.value!='')
         {
         $this = $(this);
         $.ajax(
                       {

                     url: 'include/search.php',
                         type: 'post',
                         data:{data:$data},
                         datatype: 'html',
                         async:true,
                         success: function(data){

                         $('table >tbody').append(data);

                            $result_row = $('table >tbody >tr').length;

                           // display no result found row
                            if($result_row == 0) { $('#no_found_result').css('display','');}  
                            else { $('#no_found_result').css('display','none'); }

                         }
                     });


      }else
      {
           $this = $(this);
         $.ajax(
                       {

                     url: 'view/alumni/alumni.php',

                         datatype: 'html',
                         async:true,
                         beforeSend : function(){
                         //  $('#ajax_loader').show(); 
                            $('#content').hide();
                         },
                         success: function(data){
                        // $('#ajax_loader').hide();    
                 $box = $('#content');
                         $box.after(data);
                         $box.remove();

                         }
                     });



      }




}
$(document).on('keyup','#search_alumni',$(this),search_alumni);
```

There is any way for two load pages in php and ajax based on if else condition.

Comment: Based on what i can see, this should work. Have you checked your JavaScript error console? Does that give any errors, if so; what errors?

Comment: how to see javascript error console

Comment: If you are using firefox than ```ctrl+shift+k``` ,for chrome ```ctrl+shift+j```.

Comment: @kavita,what is this element which refer using ```#search_alumni```. If it is the ```input``` box than why are you using ```$data.value!=''```. Can you explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use val() dont need use value.

```
...
 $data = $('#search_alumni').val();
   if($data!='')
...
```